# Store and Retrieve an NSArray with million elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-retrieval

I have an array which contains about one million strings. I want to store it in a file and each time the app launches, I can load all those strings to the NSArray.

I tried with two solutions:

1. Using plist file: store `[NSArray writeToFile:]` and retrieve `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:]`
2. Using SQLite with FMDB library and retrieve with SELECT query.

But they all have same problem that is the retrieving time is long ( > 5 seconds in iPhone 5).

Is there another way to do this more efficient ?

Comment: The obvious solution is not to pull the data into memory.  Just leave it in the SQLite DB and retrieve the data you need

Comment: But I need to load to array to use binary searching algorithm.

Comment: Why not build an index in your SQLite database and search it that way?